# Java package declaration: Netbeans says: 'Incorrect Package'

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to Java, Netbeans, and the IB Java API.

I downloaded the IB Java API software and I am using Netbeans to look at it.

On one of the files, Netbeans is indicating a problem with the file.

At the very top of the file, the author has placed a package declaration:

package samples.rfq;

Netbeans is using a red-dot to the left of the package declaration to tell me that it has a problem with the package declaration.

When I mouse-hover the package declaration, Netbeans tells me this:

Incorrect Package
(Alt-Enter shows hints)

On my Mac-keyboard I press Alt-Enter and Netbeans just interprets that as an Enter (and then I need to undo that Enter).

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I work around the Alt-Enter-bug to see the hints?
2. What do you typically do when Netbeans indicates 'Incorrect Package' on one of your package declarations?

Answer (score 5):

In java packages have to follow the directory structure. So if you declare your package as `package samples.rfq;` then your class has to be in the directory samples/rfq/.

So to fix this error you either change the package declaration or move your class into the directory given as package.

Answer (score 3):

package declaration should be the first statement in a java class,unless the class is in the default package

when netbeans says "Incorrect Package",I add this line before the beginning of the class

```
package Test;
```

assuming the class is inside the folder "Test"